# Angular 7/Jasmine: Issues while unit testing Observable in a service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, promise, jasmine, observable

I'm having some issues testing a Service that has an Observable being subscribed in the method I want to test.  The Observable itself wraps a Promise using from(), coming from a legacy AngularJS service called 'legacyData', as such:

Service to test:

```js
refreshData(storageService: StorageService): void {
   let dataObs: Observable<IResponse> = from(this.legacyData.get({}));
   console.log("This is called while testing!!!);  <<<<

   dataObs.subscribe((response: IResponse) => {
        console.log("This is NOT called while testing!!!);  <<<<
        let responseData: IResponseData[] = response.data as IResponseData[];
        storageService.set(responseData);
    },
    (error: string) => loggingService.addError('Failed to get Data', error));
}
```

The test, using MockLegacyDataService to mock the legacy service using promises:

```js
describe('dataService', () => {
    let service: DataService;
    let storageService: StorageService;
    class MockLegacyDataService {
        get(params: object) {
            return Promise.resolve('some response');
        }
    }
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {provide: 'Data', useClass: MockLegacyDataService},
                DataService,
                StorageService
            ]
        });
        service = TestBed.get(DataService);
        storageService = TestBed.get(StorageService);
    });
    it('should refresh data', () => {
        spyOn(storageService, 'set');
        service.refreshData(storageService);

        expect(storageService.get()).toEqual('some response');  <<< this is not working!!!
        expect(storageService.set).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  <<< this is not working!!!
    });
 });
```

The Observable callback code is never called as expected.

I tried also using async(), fakeAsync()/tick/flush and jasmine done() to wrap the test, but none of this worked.

Anybody has any idea how I could test this?

Comment: what about simple setTimeout and check your expectations and call done() after a delay

Comment: It seems that using a setTimeout with jasmine done() indeed does the trick.  However I am a bit confused.  I use a very small timeout (1 millisecond) and it works fine, yet using fakeAsync() (or worse case async), which would be my preferred solution fails.  Why can't I get it to work this way?  In any case though at least now I have a way to get this done, thanks!

Comment: Jasmine async() cares about await and Promises, will not end the test until promises resolve/reject (so does not worry about observable/subscription); fakeAsync() is not really async, I suspect your subscription in service runs outside its fake time zone and tick() does not really do any waiting relative to subscription.

Comment: actually I spoke too fast.  The tests are indeed working when I run them one by one, but when running all tests using karma, the results are inconsistent.  Sometimes all pass, but sometimes some of them fail with  "Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
            at <Jasmine>"

Comment: now how can you achieve that? if you put your expectations along with done() in a timeout? in the worst case the expectations might fail, but done() will always get called :-)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but this is what I'm getting nonetheless.  Could it be some issue with Jasmine itself?

Comment: one idea - if you are using interval observables and do not terminate them they (their subscriptions) might eat up all available time. or else your code generates something that does not get cleaned up and continues running, so setTimeout does not trigger correctly. You can try to check the timestamp before setTimeout and after it gets triggered. I suspect it might be drifting